# Storage pattern for getting only active items in an array

Tags: solidity

I'm developing a contract that stores multiple Games between two players.

```
struct Game {
  address player1;
  address player2;
  bool complete;
}

Game[] public games;
```

I would like to add functionality for the contract to randomly-ish assign player2 to a Game that is not yet complete.

```
function joinGame(bytes32 _commitment) public payable {
  uint256 gameId = notReallyRandomButBetterThanNothing(games.length);

  Game storage game = games[gameId];

  game.player2 = msg.sender;
}

function notReallyRandomButBetterThanNothing(uint256 _max) internal 
  pure returns(uint256) {

  return uint256(keccak256(block.timestamp)) % _max + 1;
}
```

In the example above, this will get a gameId to point to an index in the games array, but the issue is that that game might be complete.

I do not want to delete indexes from the games array when the game is complete because it will leave gaps and I do not want to shift and delete indexes because this will screw up the gameIds for other games in the array.

I also do not want to loop through the games array looking for a complete game because this could become costly.

What is the recommended storage pattern to deal with items that could be active or inactive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more details is hard to recommend a concrete solution but.. You can have a mapping for the games

```
mapping (uint256 => Game) games;
```

And an array with incomplete games

```
uint256[] incompletes;
```

Comment: This is a simple and effective solution, thank you. I will be able to delete from the incompletes array without worrying about the order of the games.